# Command to check the number of pages passed to the printer

Tags: windows-xp, cmd, batch-file

I have a batch file that prints a bunch of PDFs, and I want to be able to iterate a command over the amount of pages that the print job has sent to the printer.

Is there a CMD command to pull the page number from a specific print job? If you have a way to do it without a dependency, cool, but if not, oh well. I'll still use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `wmic` command to get needed information via WMI. Using

```
wmic printjob get
```

you'll get full information about all print jobs, or

```
wmic printjob get Caption, TotalPages
```

to get only a basic info.

For details see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784189(WS.10).aspx and for more examples see http://www.windows-commandline.com/2011/11/manage-print-jobs-command-line.html

Comment: This would be ideal, however, attempting to pull the page number of the file could be difficult. Running `WMIC printjob` when an item is printing shows information about the job, however, some of the output will be blank depending on certain criteria. For example, the output for the field "JobStatus" is blank if it's the current job, however, additional jobs shows "Queued" in the output, which makes it hard to get the page# output because delims shift.

Comment: you can use /format:csv switch and parse the output with for command:
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=," %A in ('wmic printjob get caption^,totalpages /format:csv') do @echo.%A %B %C %D

Comment: oh nice. didn't know about the get command. works beautifully.

Comment: Quick question: Is there a way to omit an item from the get command? looking at the switches available, I don't see one. I want to omit the `node` name from the query.

Comment: Duh!  lol thanks. Lost my mind today. Hopefully I'll find it tomorrow... I think it's under the desk somewhere next to a loose cheetoh and dust bunnies.

Comment: but how do we track the current page number? can we obtain that also from the Command Prompt? Thus we could track both total pages and current number of page being printed ... if possible. @MBu

Comment: it cant get the total copy. only the page passed by.